# click on div with object svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

No working click. Why?

```
<div  id="svg" style="position: absolute; width: 140px; height: 150px;">
       <object  data="./svg/index.svg" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
</div>
```

No work

1

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#svg").click(function() {

        console.log("click");

    });
});
```

also not work

2

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#svg').on('click',function(){

        console.log("click");

    });
});
```

Comment: 1. Not error in the console 2.<object  data="./svg/index.svg" svg", and here  jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3J85R  in html

Comment: your example works, but there are differences as implemented SVG, my example not working

Comment: This is - jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DA4LN work. But my first example not working, although all equally

Comment: If you click on a picture - nothing happens. Fulfills click if you click on div (green). But you need to click svg - a wrapper div http://jsfiddle.net/uke23/

Comment: pointer-events: none; :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you must invalidate the `pointer-events` of the object.

Code:

```
#svg object{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/uke23/1/

Comment: Thanks! I was having problems with an SVG that was somehow catching clicks, despite it was contained in a div that should have stayed in the background! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try writing the code on document ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#svg").click(function() {
  console.log("click");
});
})
```

Comment: Not work!!! ----------------------------------------------------$(document).ready(function(){ $("#svg").click(function() {},   $('#svg').on('click',function(){})Not work!!! If delete <object ..../ > it works!!!